# Range with 2 conditions using for each statement and if statement

Tags: excel, vba

Part of my invoice generator code is to move data from the invoice template to another worksheet. However, some products do not have barcodes of which I need to have a code to run with separately.

So far the code below is what I tried but seems not working. It only doesn't seem to check if a cell for range("B20:B32") contains either a or b.

I would Like that whenever each cell between b20 to b32 = a then it runs the codeA otherwise if a cell between b20 to b32 = b then it will run the codeB.

my other option is to write a code for each cell between b20 to b32 but my code is very long and I have 8 cells to check if its value is = a or b.

please help. Thank you

```
            Private Sub Testfor()
            Dim cell As Range
            Dim r As Long
            Dim pd As Range

            r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            Set pd = Sheet1.Range("B20:B32")
            For Each cell In pd

            'codeA
            If cell = "DPS" Or cell = "TS" Then

            Sheet2.Cells(r, 1) = "yes"
            Sheet2.Cells(r, 2) = "yes"
            Sheet2.Cells(r, 3) = "yes"

            'codeB
            ElseIf cell = "FMC" Or cell = "PM" Or cell = "FC" Then

            Sheet2.Cells(r, 1) = "K"
            Sheet2.Cells(r, 2) = "v"
            Sheet2.Cells(r, 3) = "c"

            End If

             Next cell



            End Sub
```

Comment: actually getting a runtime error with this code... after changing it the second condition withe elseif from if

Comment: Could you tell what is the purpose of `r` variable? Do you want the result in the Sheet2 to be corresponding to the cell from Sheet1? For example if the value in B20 in Sheet1 = "DPS", the value in A20, B20 and C20 in Sheet2 should be "yes"?

Comment: You need to qualify your worksheets and instances of `Cells` object. Also, I highly recommend not dimming a variable as `Cell` as you did above. Use `iCell` or something else.

Comment: okay will try that.

Comment: Kirszu, I created r because I want to transfer data to Sheet2 if  a cell range(B20:B32) is DPS then I have a code for it. For example, I B20 is DPS then CodeA will be used where in sheet2:
            Sheet2.Cells(r, 1) = "yes"
            Sheet2.Cells(r, 2) = "yes"
            Sheet2.Cells(r, 3) = "yes"

if B21 is PM then codeB will run where in sheet2:
Sheet2.Cells(r, 1) = "K"
            Sheet2.Cells(r, 2) = "v"
            Sheet2.Cells(r, 3) = "c"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and tell if it's doing what you wanted to achieve.
You should put `r` inside the loop if you want to change it in each iteration.

```
Private Sub Testfor()
Dim cell As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim pd As Range
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet: Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet: Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Set pd = Sheet1.Range("B20:B32")
For Each cell In pd
r = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    If cell = "DPS" Or cell = "TS" Then
        Sheet2.Cells(r, 1) = "yes"
        Sheet2.Cells(r, 2) = "yes"
        Sheet2.Cells(r, 3) = "yes"
    ElseIf cell = "FMC" Or cell = "PM" Or cell = "FC" Then
        Sheet2.Cells(r, 1) = "K"
        Sheet2.Cells(r, 2) = "v"
        Sheet2.Cells(r, 3) = "c"
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it and it worked. I did the same code but it didnt work. I didnt have r inside For so probably thats why. Thank you so so much!

Comment: Yes, your code was correct, but if you want to change the variable dynamically, you need to put it inside a loop :) Please consider marking my answer as "accepted" if you think that it solved your problem (https://stackoverflow.com/tour).